# Cannot install tftpd-hpa

Tags: networking, apt, docker, pxe, cluster

I'm trying to run `apt-get install dnsmasq pxelinux syslinux-common` through a cluster control node, and keep getting this error while installing.

```
Job for tftpd-hpa.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status tftpd-hpa.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript tftpd-hpa, action "start" failed.
● tftpd-hpa.service - LSB: HPA's tftp server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tftpd-hpa; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-05-18 12:42:03 EDT; 10ms ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 15949 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tftpd-hpa start (code=exited, status=71)

May 18 12:42:02 anthonys-cluster systemd[1]: Starting LSB: HPA's tftp server...
May 18 12:42:02 anthonys-cluster tftpd-hpa[15949]:  * Starting HPA's tftpd in.tftpd
May 18 12:42:03 anthonys-cluster in.tftpd[15975]: cannot bind to local IPv4 socket: Address already in use
May 18 12:42:03 anthonys-cluster systemd[1]: tftpd-hpa.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=71/OSERR
May 18 12:42:03 anthonys-cluster systemd[1]: tftpd-hpa.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 18 12:42:03 anthonys-cluster systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: HPA's tftp server.
dpkg: error processing package tftpd-hpa (--configure):
 installed tftpd-hpa package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tftpd-hpa
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is the output from `ifconfig`

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:b3:49:90:ad  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker_gwbridge: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:a3ff:fe62:49f2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:a3:62:49:f2  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 135  bytes 27926 (27.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s25: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.186  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::50a:8d5:b9c1:c8ef  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:ae:ed:7b:8a:fc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 433599  bytes 628271274 (628.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 62  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 55323  bytes 18656592 (18.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xaa000000-aa020000  

enx8cae4cfd9c9b: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.42.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.42.0.255
        inet6 fe80::3939:f3fa:f9f5:da4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 8c:ae:4c:fd:9c:9b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 595  bytes 205585 (205.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 950  bytes 234026 (234.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enx8cae4cfd9f86: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.42.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.42.1.255
        inet6 fe80::9294:993b:90c8:b630  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 8c:ae:4c:fd:9f:86  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 891  bytes 370852 (370.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 703  bytes 177021 (177.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 57907  bytes 614653529 (614.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 57907  bytes 614653529 (614.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

My overall goal is to have nodes of a cluster PXE boot and connect to a docker swarm located on the control node. Right now, im following the instructions shown here: `https://manski.net/2016/09/pxe-server-on-existing-network-dhcp-proxy-on-ubuntu/`. How can I get passed the error shown above? Is there an easier way to do this?

Edit: I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 on the control node, and all other nodes are set to PXE boot.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Did you install another tftp server first?  The error seems to be clearly that something else is listening on the tftp port (69)

```
in.tftpd[15975]: cannot bind to local IPv4 socket: Address already in use
```

To see what is listening on the port try

```
ss -lpn | grep :69
```

Some other tips for the same error

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359630/the-tftpd-hpa-doesnt-start-after-update